# how to draw charts using rhomobile

Tags: mobile-phones, rhomobile

Can anybody please suggest if it is possible to draw graphs using rhomobile ? Theoretically since it uses java script i was wondering if i use the raphael.js to plot graphs would it work on all devices. I have to build a mobile app which will plot charts. This app should work on iphone, android phones, RIM and symbian mobiles.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

RhoMobile uses a WebView, which has the same capabilities as the devices browser, so yes, you could use any JavaScript charting library.  However, you will be limited to the devices capabilities (e.g. you will run into issues with older BlackBerry models)